# How to write caller address of a function in testing?

Tags: testing, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have a function call like this:

```
await multisig.connect(acc5).verify(from,to,value,_signature)
```

i want to check that caller address of the `verify()` is equal to the `from`, how can i write this in ether.js??

I am expecting `acc5` is equal to `from`, how to check this in testing??

Answer (score 1):

Each `ethers` account is an object that contains property `address`. So you can validate `acc5.address` against the `from` value.

```
const isTheSame = acc5.address == from;
```